# How to adding the OpenERP datasource to Pentaho Report Designer 3.9.1?

Tags: odoo, pentaho, odoo-8, openerp-7, pentaho-report-designer

I am using Pentaho Report Designer 3.9.1

OpenERP Datasource Menu does not appear in the advanced tab

like add OpenERP DataSource

Data->Add Data Source->Advanced->OpenERP Data Access

I found some references from a different website with this menu:

[image]

I haven't found it in Report Designer, though.

[image]

Aanybody could help me figure out how I can enable the OpenERP Data Access Menu?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/WillowIT/Pentaho-reports-for-OpenERP) article it says,

> End users of OpenERP can design reports using Pentaho report designer
>   v5.0 through v5.4

Therefore those versions show up the said menu in PRD.

But still there's a way to install it for 3.9 version. Follow [this](http://pvandermpentaho.blogspot.de/2012/05/adding-openerp-datasource-to-pentaho.html).